# why do not mouseover icon set in laravel 5.2 blade file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

In My laravel 5.2 application I have jquery function to mouseover display edit and trash icons in each div table. see my scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("a.editInline").css("display","none");

$('li').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
     $(this).find('.editInline').toggle();
     //find the closest li and find its children with class editInLine and 
     //toggle its display using 'toggle()'
});
</script>

  @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>


@endforeach
```

but in my blade view all edit and trash icons displaying and not working mouseover display function.

I need this type edit and trash icons displacing system.
 https://jsfiddle.net/VaibhavD/6aehaxr6/2/embedded/result/

how can I fix My codes as above example?

Comment: need some help..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. Just include Bootstrap file and change icon names like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
$("a.editInline").css("display","none");

$('li').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
     $(this).find('.editInline').toggle();
     //find the closest li and find its children with class editInLine and 
     //toggle its display using 'toggle()'
});
</script>

  @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>


@endforeach
```

Try this ..

Comment: If its working then please upvote my anwer and accept.. please

Answer (score 0):

ok it is working as this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>


@endforeach


</head>

<script>
$("a.editInline").css("display","none");

$('li').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
     $(this).find('.editInline').toggle();
     //find the closest li and find its children with class editInLine and 
     //toggle its display using 'toggle()'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```